# Importing function from another module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Importing certain function from some folder which has needed module with this function doesn't work.

I'm using nodemailer for sending emails. I have 3 different folders with modules. The problem is in importing (require) email sending function to current module from another one. It becomes `undefined` and error is `myFunc is not a function`.
I'm doing pretty simple things like requiring function from folder with `index.js` which includes needed function. But it becomes undefined when I try to use it.

services/mailTransport.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
     secure: false, 
    auth: {
      user: 'test@test.com',
      pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

module.exports = mailTransporter;
```

services/index.js

```
const mailTransporter = require("./mailTransporter");
module.exports = { mailTransporter }
```

utils/mailTemplate.js

```
const { mailTransporter } = require("../services");

const sendEmail = function (obj, msg) {
return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'test@test.com',
        to: `${obj.to}`,
        subject: `${obj.subject}`,
        text: "plain text",
        html: "<b>" + msg + "</b>"
    };
    mailTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        mailTransporter.close();
        if (error) {
            rej(error);
        }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    res(info.messageId);
    });
})
}

module.exports = { sendEmail };
```

And finally I want to use it here in projects/emails.js

```
const { sendEmail } = require("../utils/mailTemplate");
const { vendorNotificationMessage } = require("../utils/emailMessages");

async function notifyVendors(steps) {
try {
    for(let step of steps) {
        if(step.vendor) {
            const message = vendorNotificationMessage(step);
            step.to = step.vendor.email;
            step.subject = "Step cancelling notification!";
            await sendEmail(step, message);
        }
    }
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Error in notifyVendors");
}
}

module.exports = { notifyVendors };
```

I expect that email will be sent using that `sendEmail` function. But it stops with the error `TypeError: sendEmail is not a function`.

Comment: First of all I thought that the problem is circular dependency. But there is no circular dependency. Still don't know why doesn't it work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for exporting something from a module is

```
exports.globalObjectName = localObjectName
```

So in your first file the export statement should look like this

```
exports.mailTransporter = mailTransporter
```

Comment: And why mine is incorrect? Have you read the docs of node js?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need {} when you use module.exports and require. Try `module.exports = sendEmail ;` and `const  sendEmail  = require("../utils/mailTemplate");`

Comment: That would have the same result. There is nothing wrong to export object with functions and import those functions as that object's properties.

Comment: As you said  module.exports exports an object so you can have different syntaxes:

`module.exports = nameOfYourFunction;`

`module.exports = {name: function(){}};`

`module.exports.name = function (){};`

`module.exports = {name: nameOfYourFunction};`

In the last three cases your will need to call your module like that: 

`const nameOfYourFunction = require('/path')`

`nameOfYourFunction.name;`

It as an object so nodeJS need to know the key of the object to get access to its value.

Comment: I'm using object destructuring (ES6).